# Count similar words in array with and without case

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array full of words an I need to count similar words the user choose whether to sort it ignoring the cases or not

```
function parseText(text,letterCase,punc) {
    var words = text
        .replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g, '')
        .split(/\s/); //split the array and remove punctualitis

    words.forEach(function(w) {
        if (!Sub_Word[w]) {
            Sub_Word[w] = 0;
        }

        Sub_Word[w]+=1;//creating an array and the word and how much it was there
    });

    return Sub_Word;
}
```

Now this code works put it doesn't work one cases for example this array `["he","He","hello"]`

I need it to return `[["he:2"],[hello:1]]`

Comment: I'm close-voting this as unclear, since there are a few ambiguities about what you want and how you want it, and you're adding new criteria  on the go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use array.reduce:

```js
var words = ["he","He","hello"];
var res = words.reduce((m, o) => {
  o = o.toLowerCase();
  var found = m.find(e => e[0] === o);
  found ? found[1]++ : m.push([o, 1]);
  return m;
}, []);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Your answer is returning Array of objects `[{"he":2},{"hello":1}]` but OP wants array of arrays `[["he:2"],[hello:1]]`

Comment: @VicJordan `[["he:2"],[hello:1]]` is not an array of array.

Comment: I am not talking here about validation but structure only. Hope you understand what I mean. I already upvoted but wanted to have this correction.

Comment: yes i need array of arrays @VicJordan

Comment: @loay I got you already but if you need key and value as pair in that case array of objects would be better (the first answer posted by @Faly)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.reduce()` and  `Object.entries()` :

```js
let arr = ["he","He","hello"];
let lettercase = true;
let result = Object.entries(arr.reduce((a,curr)=>{
  let key = lettercase ? curr.toLowerCase() : curr;
  a[key] = a[key] || 0;
  a[key]++;
  return a;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: yes put in case of this array ["He","he ","hello"] i want the result to be [["He:2"],["hello:1"]] if it's coverted to lower case this wont happend

Comment: @loay please could you elaborate. Exactly what are you looking for.

Comment: yes i need to count simmilar word and put the result in array of arrays like the example ... now the user chooses weather to ignore the letter case or not by sending the parameter lettercase to be true if its true then the word "He" and "he " is the same and counted twice @amrender singh

Comment: @loay updated the answer please have a look